# Create Android app using API that reference JAXBContext

Tags: android, jaxb

I am a Computer Science undergraduate student and I am creating an Android app that using an API to interact with an execution server.

The server takes a xml file and do various stuff with it(get data, process data etc.)and then gives back data as output. Both input and output are exchanged via this API.

The problem is that the API references code from `javax.xml.bind`, for example, JAXBContext while android doesn't have javax.xml.bind package in its core. (a well known issue)

Feasible solutions on the internet seems to be repackaging the code I need, but I don't know exactly what suppose to be.

Since the API reference classes in `javax.xml.bind` and `javax.net`, I guess I have to extract code from these 2 packages and make them part of the API *(I have access to API source)* and then repackage the API. However, I guess **classes inside javax.xml.bind might have dependencies on other classes that not supported by Android**, so does javax.net. (Please forgive me if this is stupid thought...)

So anyone know **:** whether there are classes, which codes in javax.xml.bind and javax.net depends on, not supported by android ?

Bit of tricky question really..

I will be really appreciated if you can provide a work around that **enable a Android app to call an API that reference codes inside javax.xml.bind.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try JiBX (http://jibx.sourceforge.net/), it's a small and fast footprint, Android compatible, XML binding framework.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but using JiBX means that I need to reimplement those parts of API that reference JAXB, which is a huge amount of work...

Comment: Thanks! The key is indeed: XML binding for Android !

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with repacking those package which exists in standard Java library but not in Android. Basically, just get source code of all those missing packages and then put them into the API source and rename them into a name that is different from the original one and then change corresponding code in API that reference these methods as well (you have to use a different name, otherwise code reference methods in these package will still looking for methods in the core Library (i.e Android API)

Anyway, hope it helps. If you have the same problem.

If you have any better suggestion. Please share it!